# How to change Custom Spinner Text color android

Tags: android, xml, textview, spinner

I am working on a android project where i have to implement a custom spinner in the register form for selecting the Profession,Family name. Spinner functionality is working fine but spinner is a custom spinner and  its not accepting the text color to be changed. Is there any way i can change the color of the text?

Below is my **xml** code:

```
<com.infantstudio.CatholicMithrulu.Spinner.SearchableSpinnerProfestion
    android:id="@+id/profestion_spinner"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/profestion"
    app:hintTextCountry="Select"/>
```

Comment: post row file of spinner and in that have you given text color of textview ?

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using custom spinner. You should also bind the data with custom view or custom list. You should change the text color of custom list.

Answer (score 0):

For creating the custom spinner you need to set the custom layout in which you change the text color like the following example

```
ArrayAdapter<String>  arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_adapter, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.profestion));
    profestion_spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

you may chnage the text color here:-
**spinner_adapter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
    android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:textColor="@color/txt_color">

</TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take the spinner_adapter.xml you can set text color. But if you want to change the text color dynamically based on conditional values this won't work